# MeteorJS: Setting reactive vars in jQuery function blocks

Tags: jquery, meteor

I'm having an issue with Meteor `ReactiveVar` in an `onRendered` block. Here is my code:

```js
Template.posts.onRendered(function() {

 // get current value for limit, i.e. how many posts are currently displayed
 var limit = this.limit.get();

 $(window).scroll(function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
   // increase limit by 10 and update it
   limit += 10;
   this.limit.set(limit);
  }
 });
});
```

I'm successfully getting the limit var as tested in a `console.log()` but when trying to set it in the `$(window).scroll` block I get the following console error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined`. I know this is about scoping but I have no idea how to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is not template instance inside jQuery function, since the scope has already changed, so you need to save reference and send it.

```
Template.posts.onRendered(function() {

    // get current value for limit, i.e. how many posts are currently displayed
    var limit = this.limit.get();
    var template = this;

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            // increase limit by 10 and update it
            limit += 10;
            template.limit.set(limit);
        }
    });
});
```